# C - Doubly list insert depending on value

Tags: c, list, linked-list, insert, doubly-linked-list

So, i'm trying to create a function that inserts nodes in the doubly list at specific positions depending on the book's rating and the book's title. So if a book has rating = 3 and name "A" it goes in front of a book with rating = 2 and title "A" and the second book goes in front of a book with rating = 2 and title "B".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct Book
{
    char title[40];
    double rating;
    struct Book *next, *prev;
};

void insert(struct Book **head, struct Book **tail, double value, char *titl)
{
    if (*head == NULL)
    {
              struct Book *current;
              current = (struct Book*) malloc (1*sizeof(struct Book));
              strcpy(current -> title, titl);
              current -> rating = value;
              current -> prev = NULL;
              current -> next = NULL;
              *head = current;
              *tail = current;
    }
    else
    {
            struct Book *current,*temp;
            current = (struct Book*) malloc (1*sizeof(struct Book));
            strcpy(current -> title, titl);
            current -> rating = value;
            temp = *head;
            while (temp -> next != NULL)
            {
                if (temp -> rating < value)
                {
                    if(titl < temp -> title)
                    {
                        temp -> next = current;
                        current -> prev = *tail;
                        current -> next = NULL;
                        (*tail) -> next = current;
                        *tail = current;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                temp = temp -> next;

            }
    }
}


void displayList(struct Book *head)
{
    struct Book *current;
    if(head == NULL)
        printf("List is empty!\n");

    else
    {
    current= head ;
        while(current != NULL)
        {
            printf("%2.f %s",current -> rating, current -> title);
            current = current -> next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    struct Book *head, *tail;
    head = tail = NULL;

    insert(&head,&tail,0,"Black");
    insert(&head,&tail,4,"Air");
    insert(&head,&tail,5,"Elephant");
    insert(&head,&tail,7,"Cat");
    insert(&head,&tail,5,"Dragon");
    displayList(head);
}
```

Right now i only get "0 Black" when i display my list. Meaning i only have one item in my list. I want the output to be:

(7 Cat) (5 Dragon) (5 Elephant) (4 Air) (0 Black)

Comment: 1) create a compare() function 2) use that function to find the place for insertion 3) insert the new node there 4) profit!

Comment: @wildplasser I want the comparison in the insert function, i don't want a separate function for that.

Comment: Make it static, and it will be inlined.

Comment: @wildplasser I don't know what you mean. The thing is, i don't know if my comparison is correct in the above code, and the problem is that after running the above, i only have one item on the list and not five.

Comment: @user3120283: extract the comparison code into a function, and prefix it with `static inline`. If your compiler objects to `inline`, either tell it to accept C11 or C99, or get a better compiler, or drop the keyword `inline` but note that you are using an archaic compiler. Now you have the comparison code in a separate function, you can test it, independently of the code that inserts into the list. This alone is valuable. The chances are that you'll have other uses for the function, but even if not, separating different functions properly is valuable; it makes the program easier to understand.

Comment: Note that the dot `.` and arrow `->` operators bind very tightly.  It is not appropriate to put spaces around them.  It is an aconventional layout to include spaces around those operators.

Comment: The comparison code is not correct, IMO.  Further, your element insertion code only kicks in when both the rating (`value`) and title sort before the current node.  If the new item belongs at the end of the non-empty list, you don't ever add it.  Because `0 Black` belongs at the start of the list, you never add any other nodes (you simply leak the memory allocated for it). You don't seem to fix up the back-links (`prev` links) properly; you wouldn't be able to traverse the list backwards.

Comment: `I don't know if my comparison is correct` That is the advantage of a compare function: you can test it separately. Divide&conquer.

Comment: `if(titl < temp -> title)` :: for instance, you are comparing pointers here, while you probably want to compare the objects that they point to: strings. (HINT: use one of the strcmp() functions here)

Comment: @wildplasser I did change my code, and used the strcmp() function for the string comparison, but i still don't know what to change to get all the books in the list. [Here's](http://ideone.com/uwjlKK) what i have now.